# How to convert this strange (HEX?) string to ASCII - PLAIN

Tags: javascript, binary, type-conversion, base64, hex

My Webservice return a strange format , I neet that string plain...

I tried to convert to ascii but return a strange thing

I tried this function but doesnt work...

```
  function hex_to_ascii(str1) {
                                  var hex = str1.toString();
                                  var str = '';
                                  for (var n = 0; n < hex.length; n += 2) {
                                      str += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(hex.substr(n, 2), 16));
                                  }
                                  return str;
                              }
```

STEPS
**INSERT** ASCII (type IMAGE field in table) ---data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAA ...
**SELECT** HEX --- 0x646174613A696D6167652F6A70..
**WEBSERVICE** RARE ---- ZGF0YTppbWFnZS9qcGVnO2J...

I need to convert in javascript that rare to ASCII/Plain again

Comment: That's not hexadecimal. It could be base64 though I think it's best for you to find out why your webservice returns in that format.

Comment: When I do select query it returns me;
https://pastebin.com/6xXLLMik

STEPS

INSERT ASCII  (type IMAGE field in table)
SELECT HEX
WEBSERVICE RARE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is base64 encoded image which is base64 encoded again. Just use the `atob()` javascript native function instead of your `hex_to_ascii()` function.

Example:

```
atob("ZGF0YTppbWFnZS9qcGVnO2Jhc2...Z1J2L0FQL1o") // your full string
```

Which return:

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJ...
```